# pass char* to dll function from C# project

Tags: c#, c

I have exported function in Visual Studio C++ dll project:

```
extern "C" int _stdcall init(char* buff, const char* aData)
```

Have declared it in C#:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int init(StringBuilder buff, StringBuilder aData);
```

And call it from C# application

```
StringBuilder sResult = new StringBuilder(1024);
last_res = DllApi.init(sResult, new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText("aaaaaaa")));
```

Got exception:

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'A call to PInvoke function 'xxxxx::init' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling
```

What is wrong with my declaration?

Comment: Why CallingConvention.Cdecl when the C declaration clearly spells out stdcall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ function definition quite clearly says the calling convention is StdCall, which is the default on `DllImport` so just don't set it.

Also you don't need `StringBuilder` for the second parameter as it's `const`.

```cs
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int init(StringBuilder buff, string aData);
```